# Qualtrics - Adding a Maze Game

Tags: qualtrics

I am pretty new on Qualtrics and have no experience with HTML & Javascript. We want to embed a simple maze game into our survey. We are looking for open sources like this:
https://github.com/troyphillips/Daily-Maze-Solver
I need help on whether this is doable and what code I should add where. I would appreciate any advice or sample codes other than adding from the source here.

In general, we try to embed samples of mazes into the survey that players can only complete with navigating.